# Unix: carts exercice

Tags: unix, grep

So I have to make an exercise for Informatics and I can't find the solution to this problem.

`δ = { h ∈ H | the carts of h are ordened by a color}` (between two carts of the same color there are never carts of an other color) examples:

```
9s5s4sKs7h6h4h2d4dAdTd2c3c ∈ δ

5s9sTs8hKhJc4s6c4hJsAc2dKs ∉ δ
```

The colors are defined by `c,d,h,s`. How can I use the `grep` command to only shows the lines where this collection is defined?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you re looking for a regular expression which finds strings that can contain (among other things) the letters c, d, h, s and they need to be in that order (or actually, the reverse order judging from your first example).

Comment: They don't need to be in that order

Comment: Apparently "carts" means "cards", and "color" means "suit". If you really meant color, then `shdc` would be invalid. Spades and clubs are the same color (black).

Comment: sorry it's difficult to translate my dutch exercices to english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -E '^([^hdc]*[^shc]*[^sdc]*[^sdh]*)\s[a-z]+' greptxtfile
```

which matches in order s.. h.. d.. c and nothing in between that is invalid.  This assumes there are no other cart types.

```
Kc3c7c4c9cJc8cAc5c6cTcQc2c fractieleidsters
7c4c6cKcTcQc2c9c8cAcJc5c3c kastpapier
6c4cTc8c3cJc5cQcAc2c7cKc9c klankvormen
7cKc6c5c8cQcJc4cTcAc9c3c2c wrijfkussens
7s9sAd9d7d3h8h5hQhAcTc4c7c continenties
2cQcTc3c7cAcJc9cKc6c8c4c5c aanschaffingsprijs
3c9cKcAcTc7c6c2c5cQc8c4cJc platenspelertje
TcKc3c8cJc4c9c2cAcQc5c6c7c pinkstervakanties
2c4c7cJc8cTcKcQc9c6c3c5cAc lachspel
Kc4c6c3c5cAc2c8cQcTc7cJc9c vrouwenharten
Jc7cQc5cKc6c3c9cAcTc8c4c2c dagorders
AcJcTc3c2c5c8c6c7cKc4c9cQc overstraald
QcJc3c7c5c9c4cTc6c2cKcAc8c verlangzaam
2c8cKcTcAcQc7c5cJc3c6c9c4c kortverbander
7c5cKc8cAcJcQcTc2c3c9c6c4c uitnodigingskaarten
Tc8c9c3c4cQcKcAcJc2c6c7c5c vossenhuid
7cJc3c8c4cTcKc5cAc9c6cQc2c beleenden
AcKc9c2cQc4cJc8cTc5c7c6c3c nazidom
5cQc2c7c9cTc6cAc8c3cJc4cKc tennisland
9c8c4c6c3cJc5cAc7cTcQcKc2c parochiepriesters
7c3c6c2c5cJcTc8c4cQc9cAcKc woonwagenwet
Ts8s9sKd3d7d6h5h4hAh8hKc3c gezinnetjes
7s9sAsQsTd6d5hQh9cJcAc3c8c lichtkegels
Ac8c7cTc9c4c3cKc5cJcQc6c2c snottige
8c9c7cJc4c3cQcAc2cKcTc5c6c papyrusteksten
9cJc7c8c2c6c5cTc4c3cQcAcKc middelgroot
6cQc3cTc7cAc4cJc9cKc5c2c8c onderhoudscontract
```

Comment: It doens't show anything, you can get the file from http://computergebruik.ugent.be/oefeningenreeks1/kaarten1.txt.

Comment: You actually don't need to take the words in account, how can you delete them from the grep command?

Comment: you can use ^([^ hdc]*[^ shc]*[^ sdc]*[^ sdh]*)  which make sure you don't match the space, and it starts from the beginning of the line

Comment: I figured that out but the suits are not always ordened together.  E.g. 'ThJh8sTd2cTs4cQc7d3d4hKh9c' is a part of the collection but the last 'c' in this exemple is not ordened with the other 'c's. How could I fix this problem?

Comment: the original answer doesn't include this false positive, stick with that one.

Comment: Well that's not the right answer, i'll look into it. Thanks though.